# How can 蛙 be read as あ ("a") in Asui Tsuyu's name?

Tags: japanese-language, my-hero-academia

In Japanese, Asui Tsuyu's name is written as 蛙吹 梅雨. Most of the kanji in her name makes sense. 梅雨 is read as つゆ ("tsuyu"), and 吹 is read as すい ("sui"), but from what I know 蛙 is read primarily as かえる ("kaeru"), and can also be read as かわず ("kawazu") or かいる ("kairu"), but I can't find anything about reading it as "a". Moreover, it isn't a jōyō kanji or a jinmeiyō kanji, so I find it unlikely that it's something that happens when the kanji is used in names, as it generally shouldn't be used in names at all. So what's the deal?

Comment: You might also be interested in our sister site, [japanese.se] for more general Q&A on the Japanese language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[蛙](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%9B%99%20%23kanji) has ア【a】 as one of the *on-yomi***, and kanji compound is usually read in *on-yomi* (some also have a reading in *kun-yomi*, but in general, all of the kanji in the kanji compound are read in either *kun-yomi* only or *on-yomi* only, but not mixed).

Some example where [蛙 is read as "a"](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%9B%99%20%E3%81%82):

> - 蛙黽 (***a***bou): tree frog (toad)
> - 蛙鳴 (***a***mei): frog calling​
> - 蛙鳴蝉噪 (***a***meisensou): annoying noise; fruitless argument; useless controversy

As for Asui, her kanji representation 蛙吹 is read in *on-yomi* as 蛙（ア） and [吹（スイ）](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%90%B9%20%23kanji)